# how to delete the order notification to the vendor, only the admin receives the notification

Tags: woocommerce, dokan

where can I find answers to this problem, how to turn off order notifications to the vendor, let the admin only receive notifications on each order thank you

[image: this is the default code that I see, in the multivendor dokan plugin]

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: this is the default code that I see, in the multivendor dokan plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* Filter orders of current user
*
* @param object $args
* @param object $query
* @since 2.9.4
* @return object $args
*/
function dokan_filter_orders_for_current_vendor( $args, $query ) {
global $wpdb;

if ( current_user_can( ‘manage_woocommerce’ ) ) {
if ( ! empty( $_GET[‘vendor_id’] ) ) {
$getdata = wp_unslash( $_GET );

$vendor_id = wc_clean( $getdata[‘vendor_id’] );
$args[‘join’] .= ” LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}dokan_orders as do ON $wpdb->posts.ID=do.order_id”;
$args[‘where’] .= ” AND do.seller_id=$vendor_id”;
}
```